# Query Tuning in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, sql-tuning

I have a query that is running in 17s, but I can not think of a way to optimize this query. Some help is much needed.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
CREATE materialized VIEW professores_fizeram_planejamentoTEST as
    SELECT unities.id as id_escola,
           unities.name as nome_escola,
           teachers.id as id_professor,
           teachers.name as nome_professor,
           datas.dia,
           COALESCE((SELECT true
               FROM lesson_plans
              WHERE lesson_plans.teacher_id = teachers.id and
                datas.dia between lesson_plans.start_at and lesson_plans.end_at
              LIMIT 1), false) as criou_plano_aula,
           COALESCE((select true
               from content_records
              where content_records.teacher_id = teachers.id and
                content_records.record_date = datas.dia
              limit 1), false) as criou_registro_conteudo
      FROM (SELECT i::date as dia,
               EXTRACT(year FROM i::date) as ano
          FROM generate_series(date_trunc('year', now()), now(), '1 day'::INTERVAL) i
          WHERE EXTRACT(dow from i::timestamp) in (1,2,3,4,5)) datas
      JOIN (SELECT distinct teacher_id, classroom_id, YEAR
          FROM teacher_discipline_classrooms) teacher_discipline_classrooms ON (teacher_discipline_classrooms.year = datas.ano)
      JOIN classrooms on (classrooms.id = teacher_discipline_classrooms.classroom_id)
      JOIN unities on (unities.id = classrooms.unity_id)
      JOIN teachers on (teachers.id = teacher_discipline_classrooms.teacher_id)
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM school_calendars
                 JOIN school_calendar_events on (school_calendar_events.school_calendar_id = school_calendars.id and
                                 school_calendar_events.event_type = 'no_school' and
                                 datas.dia between school_calendar_events.start_date and school_calendar_events.end_date)
                 WHERE school_calendars.unity_id = unities.id)
```

This query returns the following analysis

```
Nested Loop  (cost=143.840..3721.540 rows=38 width=66) (actual time=1.923..17270.125 rows=171231 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=143.690..1523.510 rows=38 width=41) (actual time=1.744..5996.571 rows=171231 loops=1)
          Join Filter: (NOT (delta 3))
          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 15249
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=143.550..203.530 rows=76 width=16) (actual time=1.661..568.049 rows=186480 loops=1)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=143.270..165.450 rows=76 width=16) (actual time=1.651..183.740 rows=186660 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: ((victor.juliet_seven)::double precision = echo_tango('quebec_four'::text, ((alpha_quebec_whiskey.alpha_quebec_whiskey)::date)::timestamp without time zone))
                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=121.700..127.820 rows=612 width=12) (actual time=1.384..3.336 rows=2388 loops=1)
                            Group Key: victor.foxtrot_six, victor.oscar_kilo, victor.juliet_seven
                          ->  Seq Scan on victor  (cost=0.000..94.400 rows=3640 width=12) (actual time=0.004..0.563 rows=3640 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=21.260..21.260 rows=25 width=8) (actual time=0.256..0.256 rows=180 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 16kB
                          ->  Function Scan on xray_yankee alpha_quebec_whiskey  (cost=0.010..21.260 rows=25 width=8) (actual time=0.081..0.195 rows=180 loops=1)
                                  Filter: (echo_tango('papa'::text, (alpha_quebec_whiskey)::timestamp without time zone) = ANY ('oscar_seven_charlie'::double precision[]))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 72
              ->  Index Scan using echo_victor on uniform  (cost=0.280..0.490 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=1 loops=186660)
                      Index Cond: (quebec_seven = victor.oscar_kilo)
        ->  Index Scan using golf on four  (cost=0.140..0.160 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=186480)
                Index Cond: (quebec_seven = uniform.xray_victor)
        SubPlan
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.280..34.110 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.027..0.027 rows=0 loops=186480)
                ->  Seq Scan on seven  (cost=0.000..1.990 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.008 rows=2 loops=186480)
                        Filter: (xray_victor = four.quebec_seven)
                        Rows Removed by Filter: 75
                ->  Index Scan using alpha_quebec_papa on two  (cost=0.280..16.050 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=372960)
                        Index Cond: (zulu = seven.quebec_seven)
                        Filter: (((xray_delta)::text = 'oscar_seven_golf'::text) AND ((alpha_quebec_whiskey.alpha_quebec_whiskey)::date >= foxtrot_three) AND ((alpha_quebec_whiskey.alpha_quebec_whiskey)::date <= lima))
                        Rows Removed by Filter: 14
  ->  Index Scan using tango on romeo  (cost=0.150..0.200 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=171231)
          Index Cond: (quebec_seven = victor.foxtrot_six)
  SubPlan
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.000..20.600 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.048..0.048 rows=0 loops=171231)
          ->  Seq Scan on five  (cost=0.000..20.600 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.045..0.045 rows=0 loops=171231)
                  Filter: ((foxtrot_six = romeo.quebec_seven) AND ((alpha_quebec_whiskey.alpha_quebec_whiskey)::date >= oscar_echo) AND ((alpha_quebec_whiskey.alpha_quebec_whiskey)::date <= xray_three))
                  Rows Removed by Filter: 246
  SubPlan
    ->  Limit  (cost=4.810..37.030 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=171231)
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on whiskey  (cost=4.810..37.030 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=171231)
                  Recheck Cond: (foxtrot_six = romeo.quebec_seven)
                  Filter: (foxtrot_tango = (alpha_quebec_whiskey.alpha_quebec_whiskey)::date)
                  Rows Removed by Filter: 28
                  Heap Blocks: exact=258248
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on juliet_bravo  (cost=0.000..4.810 rows=70 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=37 loops=171231)
                        Index Cond: (foxtrot_six = romeo.quebec_seven)
```

[EXPLAIN 1 - RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUIEU.png)
[EXPLAIN 2 - RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98gjH.png)

Thanks you.

Comment: Welcome on SO. You need to provide more details so that you can get help. Please add the actual plan of the query. And also add buffers parameter to explain `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers) SELECT ...` .

Comment: how many rows  containst  the tables  involved  by the query?

Comment: Your view is materializing 170k rows in 17 s. I think that's pretty fast.

Comment: The problem who this query result in 1 hour in consults with 100.000k

Comment: Have you tried doing the generate_series query as a CTE? (With statement).. sometimes that provides better performance, sometimes worse... of course, you could create a temp table with that info in it as well.

Comment: Your explain outputs are either images or obfuscated. Please post unobfuscated ones in text form. It looks like a simple index will do the trick, but I cannot tell on which table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- no, we wont!
- sanitize your query (add aliases, and use them, for instance)
- `COALESCE((SELECT true FROM lesson_plans WHERE lesson_plans.teacher_id = teachers.id and datas.dia between lesson_plans.start_at and lesson_plans.end_at LIMIT 1), false) as criou_plano_aula` 
  ...  can be replaced by a simple `EXISTS(subquery)`
- your outer query only refers to {unities,teachers,datas}, the rest of the tables are merely junction tables.
- if there is a difference in the queryplan between expected <-->observed, your statistics are wrong.
- the function scan on generate_series() spoils the queryplan. Better use a material calendartable, which could be indexed & countable.
- always add the tuning parameters and an estimate of the cardinalities to the question. These are not details.

Comment: How could it? * sanitize your query (add aliases, and use them, for instance)

Improved 2s in query query with this topic. * COALESCE ....

How could it? 
 *  your outer query only refers to {unities,teachers,datas}, the rest of the tables are merely junction tables.
* the function scan on generate_series() spoils the queryplan. Better use a material calendartable, which could be indexed & countable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section. If you want to speed up your query please add some information:

First, please include the execution plan. This will tell us what's going on fast.

Also, please post:

- Existing indexes on `lessons_plans`.
- Existing indexes on `content_records`.
- Rows on `teacher_discipline_classrooms`.
- Existing indexes on `teacher_discipline_classrooms`.
- Existing indexes on `classrooms`.
- Existing indexes on `unities`.
- indexes on `teachers`.
- Existing indexes on `shool_calendars`.

Comment: Yes, lessons_plans, content_records, teacher_discipline_classrooms, teacher_discipline_classrooms, teacher_discipline_classrooms, teacher_discipline_classrooms, classrooms , unities and shool_calendars have indexes on. I changed colapsed to exists and 17s to 14s.